# Headless Task use inside component with React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run a background task using `headlessjs in react-native`. The problem is that I am unable to access the async task inside the component in order to show it on the view. Here's my default component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
  NativeModules
} from 'react-native';


module.exports = NativeModules.ToastAndroid;

someTask = require('./SomeTaskName.js');



export default class test2 extends Component {

   constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
         myText: 'My Original Text'
      }
   }
   updateText = () => {
      this.setState({myText: 'My Changed Text'});s
   }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({myText: someTask});
    someTask.then(function(e){           //<--- error
      console.log("lala" + e);
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
         <View>
            <Text>
              abc
            </Text>
         </View>
    );
  }
}



AppRegistry.registerComponent('test2', () => test2);
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () => someTask);
```

As mentioned in the code, I get the error `undefined is not a function`. I don't know how to make this work. My `SomeTaskName.js` looks like this.

**SomeTaskName.js**

```
module.exports = async (taskData) => {
  return taskData.myname;
}
```

The idea is to simply get the data from the service and show it on the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to simply move the code inside the `componentDidMount` function. Here's how I achieved it.

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
  Image
} from 'react-native';


export default class test2 extends Component {

   constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
         myText: '1'
      }
   }


  componentWillUnmount() {
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    someTask = async (taskData) => {
        this.setState({ myText: taskData.myname});
    }
  };

  }
  render() {

    return (<Text>Working</Text>);
  }
}



AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () => someTask);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('test2', () => test2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace :

```
someTask = require('./SomeTaskName.js');
```

by

```
import SomeTaskName from './SomeTaskName'
```

Comment: I am already receiving the data and I can log it. the problem is with render the data in the view.