# How to open a screen from headlessTask react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My React-Native App has a headlessTask that is triggered when device receives an SMS. I want my app to open a screen when the SMS is received, even when app is not running.

I'm familiar with react-navigation, but since a headlessTask is not a component, I can't even send the navigation prop.

**What I have tried:**
[Headless Task use inside component with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322455/headless-task-use-inside-component-with-react-native)

the solution above only works if application is open.

P.S. In Native Android, I'm able to achieve this by starting the Activity inside the broadcast receiver.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same question.

Comment: No, I still haven't found the solution

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this. A work around may be? I tried Linking.openURL() from headless task but did not work.

Comment: @ali-goher-shabir, how are you? 
I saw your video on how to solve this problem, can you explain how you did it?

I tried using 'Linking.openUrl' and libraries like 'react-native-invoke-app' but without success, I think because of headlessjs not being able to open/modify UI.

Can you help me?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gaxr7u2V3A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use deep linking.
In your headless task use something like this:

```
Linking.openURL('example://sms-received/sms-data')
```

Also you should handle deep links in your app.